# Ruby on Rails (Console): Collection.where() returning ArgumentError with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I have a database where I am trying to find data within a certain range and meeting certain criteria. I am using the following command:

```
GameSlot.where("s = ? and st >= :start_date and et <= :end_date", 5, {start_date: '2016-01-01', end_date: '2017-01-01'})
```

When I execute, I get back:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)

I am a novice to Ruby on Rails so any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The datatypes for "s" is integer, "st" and "et" are time, but I am only interested in the date.

Answer (score 3):

Should be more like this, I think:

```
GameSlot.where(["s = :s and st >= :start_date and et <= :end_date", 
                s: 5, 
                start_date: '2016-01-01', 
                end_date: '2017-01-01'])
```

Note that `where` here only has one argument, an array.

Documentation on [QueryMethods#where](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where).

Comment: if my rails version is 3.2.21, will this still work?

Comment: @DeeWBee: I don't know, try it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
GameSlot.where("s = ? and st >= ? and et <= ?", 5, '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01')
```

Comment: should be an array, I think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I read the link you posted and it seems so, but i've always done it this way and works fine. I also double-checked the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions).

Comment: if my rails version is 3.2.21, will this still work?

Comment: @DeeWBee Yes, it should. Check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) for the guides rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, you could consider class methods (or scopes, if you like that sort of thing). Something like:

```
class GameSlot < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

    def s(val)                        where(s: val)             end
    def starting_on_or_after(date)    where('st >= ?', date)    end
    def ending_on_or_before(date)     where('et <= ?', date)    end

  end

end
```

Then you could do something like:

```
GameSlot.s(5).starting_on_or_after('2016-01-01').ending_on_or_before('2017-01-01')
```

That way, you leave the query logic inside the `GameSlot` model which seems a little better encapsulated (to me).

Something to chew on.

Comment: if my rails version is 3.2.21, will this still work?

Comment: Yep. There's nothing new or fancy going on here. The `class < self` bit just declares class methods. And the where clauses are just like @gerry's except separated out into the class methods.

Comment: Should be `class << self`, I think.

Comment: "if you like that sort of thing" - tell me, do you honestly prefer _that_ to scopes? I find it hard to believe :)

Comment: Honestly, yes. And it doesn't strike me *so* strange. According to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments), "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes." And, stabby lambdas give me the heebie-jeebies. Although now that I'm doing more coffeescript, I'm getting over my irrational fear of them.

Comment: @jvillian: dunno, man. To each his own, I guess, but look [how neat the scopes can be](https://monosnap.com/file/oQ8KlcHn9hYjwnh73jOYk23aZ9XLZv.png). And they are natural one-liners! (what can't be said about the methods in your answer, sadly) :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Yep, to each his own! BTW and FWIW, except for the fact that I do the `class << self` wrapper, mine are one-liners, too - no?

Comment: @jvillian: _technically_, they are on one line, yes, but would you agree that this is not very common style? (that is, I assert that normally ruby methods take at least 3 lines, def / body / end. Hence the natural vs unnatural one-liners :) )

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I suspect that you have seen *much* more code than I have. And so, I would tend to defer to your opinion on what is more or less common style.

Comment: @jvillian: ah, [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-single-line-methods) backs me up: "avoid single-line methods" :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Trust me, I am confident this is least of my sins.

Comment: @jvillian: haha. Cheers, mate.